# Is it possible for locked, shared memory to move in address space?

Tags: process, kernel, fork, shared-memory

Lets say I create a shared memory segment using `shmget` and then lock it using `shmctl` with the `SHM_LOCK` flag. The lock flag ensures that the segment will not be moved to swap, but does it guarantee that it will not change address? If not, why/when does it change address?

Reading about `mlock` , I gathered that a locked memory segment can still change address (though I don't know why/when this occurs either), but if it's also shared, it seems like it would be unexpected for the address to move.

Comment: When you say "change address", do you mean virtual address or physical address? If you mean virtual address, what gives you the idea that it is possible? Virtual addresses are your process's only handle on the memory it has allocated; it wouldn't make any sense for them to be subject to change behind the process's back. If you mean physical addresses, why do you care? Userspace processes have no need to know about those.

Comment: It makes no sense without the proper background, sorry. There are hardware performance counters that write directly to memory, and since they are not attached to a process, the process that owns the memory has to be executing when the counter is generating results, or the virtual to physical mapping will be incorrect. The memory wasn't  "changing address", it was being unmapped when the process was switched. In the case of shared memory, all processes attached can be inactive, thus unmapping the memory also